# jQuery, find next X number of instances until a match is not found

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gFZ5W/2/

What I'm trying to do is have the stats show under every section when the section title is clicked. The catch is that there can be any number of options. Right now the code is hard coded for two options.

How can I tell jQuery to show all the elements with the class `stats` until it reaches an element without `stats` then stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.showstats').click(function (event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.stats)').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gFZ5W/3/)**

This will bind the click event to the showstats anchors, traverse up the DOM to the closest `<tr>` element, and then toggle the classes of all the following `<tr>` until it hits the first one that doesn't have the stats class.